# Trigger Content Update event javascript Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I saw a lot of events `trigger('contentUpdated')`. For example: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`. My question is:

- Where is the function `contentUpdated`?
- Can anyone give me a brief description about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contentUpdated` is not a function, it is an event (similar to the `load` or `click` events).

This event is listened in `lib/web/mage/mage.js` :

```
$('body').on('contentUpdated', function () {
    if (mage) {
        mage.apply();
    }
});
```

It basically reinit the components inside a dynamic group of update elements.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh totally